# How to make Dropdownlist readonly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am using

```
TextBox.ReadOnly = false;
```

for readonly.

How can i fix it on DropDownList?

I use **Enabled = false** properties like...

```
TextBox.Enabled = false;
DropDownList.Enabled = false;
```

but, after that css class not call in this both control at run-time.

Please give me any properties like "ReadOnly".

Comment: A readonly dropdown list may as well be a label. If you can't change the value, whats the point.

Comment: Actually i want to do like this...
If i Checked that checkbox, after that i am not able to change any value of any textbox and dropdownlist.

Comment: Textbox is editable so we use readonly if nt wnt to edit , but dropdown populate at runtime , no editable so no readonly property for it

Comment: @Satindersingh: Yes Sir, I agree, So please give me other option for this.

Comment: Enabled="False" will work in this case or after checkbox checkt set visible =false for dropdown and place a label

Comment: I thing this will be batter from other any option, actually i done this :). But I want to do same like textbox, anyways if i not getting any solution then i fix it. Thanks Satinder Singh.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no readonly property for `DropDownList` in asp.net

Try using:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Enabled="False">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Or change it at runtime:

```
DropDownList1.Enabled=false;
```

and change it's css class as well.

```
DropDownList1.CssClass = "class";
```

Comment: Thanks, It's work thank you again and again, you save my time any my form design.  :)

Comment: It's worth noting that a `disabled` dropdownlist doesn't have its data accounted for on post_back. Something that does happen with read only controls.

Answer (score 13):

Another way:

**Code Behind:**  Just add attribute `disabled`

```
 DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

**Client Side:**

```
 $("#DropDownList1").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rdUXW/1/)**

Comment: I tried this, and it gives me the default value of the dropdown when I try to retrieve it from the codebehind.

Answer (score 4):

As disabled dropdownlist data cannot be read in postback. So as a workaround do not disable it, but first clear dropdownlist and then bind only already selected item.

```
ListItem item = DropDownList.SelectedItem;
DropDownList.Items.Clear();
DropDownList.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a panel as with **Enabled="false"** and put your control inside:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlname" runat="server" Enabled="false">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```